# How to loop value of radio box which is using "label for" method?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am currently using "label for"(so user can easily click on it instead of small radio button) for my radio box selection. I had 32 of different radio box, so I had to using loop to run it. But I found that it is different with the normal radio box, I cannot use the same way to loop for my radio box. How to get all the value of different radio box that I had selected? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.allrb').change(valueE);

});

function valueE(e) 
{
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);
  
  if ($radio.is('.Rb')) 
  {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  }

}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: none;
    }

    label {
      color: #9a929e;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      color: #ccc8ce;
      background: #675f6b;
      margin: auto;
    }

    label + input[type=radio] + label {
      border-left: solid 3px #675f6b;
    }

    .radio-group {
      border: solid 3px #675f6b;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    font-family: roboto;
    }

    table
    {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #tab td
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="30px">1</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three"
          name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five" name="r1" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="30px">2</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one2">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two2">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three2"
          name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three2">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four2">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five2">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="30px">3</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one3" name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one3">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two3" name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two3">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three3"
          name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three3">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four3" name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four3">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five3" name="r3" class="allrb r1"
          value="1"><label for="option-five3">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="30px">4</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one4">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two4">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three4"
          name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three4">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four4">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five4">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="30px">5</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one5">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two5">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three5"
          name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three5">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four5">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five5">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
    <td width="30px">6</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one6">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two6">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three6"
          name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three6">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four6">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five6">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
    <td width="30px">7</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one7">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two7">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three7"
          name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three7">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four7">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five7">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
    <td width="30px">8</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one8">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two8">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three8"
          name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three8">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four8">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five8">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="text" class="numTotal" name="numTot" id="numTot" disabled />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have iterated loop over the radio button and bind with click even on button.
I have added all selected values in array.

```js
$('.allrb').change(valueE);
 $('#Click').click(clickme);
 var selectedValues = [];
 function clickme() {
     $.each($('.radio-group input[type=radio]'), function(index, value) {
        
         if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
           selectedValues.push($(this).val());
         }
     });
     console.log(selectedValues);
 }

 function valueE(e) {
     var newValue = e.target.value;
     var $radio = $(e.target);

     if ($radio.is('.Rb')) {
         $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
     }

 }
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: none;
    }

    label {
      color: #9a929e;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    input[type=radio]:checked + label {
      color: #ccc8ce;
      background: #675f6b;
      margin: auto;
    }

    label + input[type=radio] + label {
      border-left: solid 3px #675f6b;
    }

    .radio-group {
      border: solid 3px #675f6b;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    font-family: roboto;
    }

    table
    {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #tab td
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="30px">1</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two" name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three"
          name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four" name="r1" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five" name="r1" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="30px">2</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one2">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two2">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three2"
          name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three2">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four2">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five2" name="r2" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five2">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="30px">3</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one3" name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one3">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two3" name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two3">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three3"
          name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three3">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four3" name="r3" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four3">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five3" name="r3" class="allrb r1"
          value="1"><label for="option-five3">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr4" name="v">
    <td width="30px">4</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one4">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two4">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three4"
          name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three4">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four4">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five4" name="r4" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five4">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr5" name="v">
    <td width="30px">5</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one5">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two5">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three5"
          name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three5">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four5">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five5" name="r5" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five5">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr6" name="v">
    <td width="30px">6</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one6">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two6">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three6"
          name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three6">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four6">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five6" name="r6" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five6">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr7" name="v">
    <td width="30px">7</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one7">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two7">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three7"
          name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three7">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four7">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five7" name="r7" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five7">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr8" name="v">
    <td width="30px">8</td>
    <td width="200px">Content</td>
    <td width="75px;">
      <div class="radio-group">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="5"><label for="option-one8">A</label><input type="radio" id="option-two8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="4"><label for="option-two8">B</label><input type="radio" id="option-three8"
          name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="3"><label for="option-three8">C</label><input type="radio" id="option-four8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb" value="2"><label for="option-four8">D</label><input type="radio" id="option-five8" name="r8" class="allrb Rb"
          value="1"><label for="option-five8">E</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<input type="text" class="numTotal" name="numTot" id="numTot" disabled />
<input type="button" value="Click Me and see console for Output" id="Click"/>
```